# Not able to write file with openFileOutput

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save some simple text in a file and then read it later.
I have created files in the same app that work fine but for some reason with this one i get a 
`FileNotFoundException` when I try to use the openFileInput() method.

```
private static final String COOKIE = "account_cookie.txt";    

public void saveAccountCookie(String accountId, String expiryDate) {
    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(openFileOutput(COOKIE, MODE_PRIVATE));
        pw.write(accountId + " " + expiryDate);
        pw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public boolean cookieValid() {
    try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(COOKIE));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String[] cookie = br.readLine().split(" ");
        br.close();
        if (checkExpiry(cookie[1])) {
            return true;
        }
        checkTrialRequest(cookie[0]);
        return false;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

these methods are called from an `AsyncTask`

Comment: I would say that you are supposed to close the `FileOutputStream` opened in `openFileOutput`. closing the `PrintWriter` is not sufficient.

Comment: I was under the impression that when you close an `InputStream` or `OutputStream` or anything like that that it closes all the streams it wraps as well?

Comment: after checking in the code, it would appear that you are right, pw.close seems to close the underlying stream. may be you'd have to flush it?

Comment: What is the file and location for which this fails?  See if you can figure out why this one is different from those that work.

Comment: This does not fix it, the .close() method flushes the stream then closes.

Answer (score -2):

First Create in your source folder an Application Class so you can handle General Stuff for the Application itself Something Like this

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp instance;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }


    public MyApp() {
        super();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return (instance == null) ? instance = new MyApp() : instance;
    }
}
```

Then try this way

```
public void saveAccountCookie(String accountId, String expiryDate) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = MyApp.getInstance().getBaseContext().openFileOutput(COOKIE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
        pw.write(accountId + " " + expiryDate);
        pw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public boolean cookieValid() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = MyApp.getInstance().getBaseContext().openFileInput(COOKIE);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String[] cookie = br.readLine().split(" ");
        br.close();
        if (checkExpiry(cookie[1])) {
            return true;
        }
        checkTrialRequest(cookie[0]);
        return false;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Tell me if this way it works. :)

Comment: I don't see how having a global application context is relevant to the question.

Comment: It's just a good practice, he should use the FileInputStream and OutputStream instead of StreamReader Directly

Comment: I don't think having a global object is a good practice. I don't see how creating a named variable instead of keeping it anonymous is a better practice.